# Line spacing and mixed font sizes

Tags: css

Anyone who knows if it is possible to keep a constant line spacing with CSS, even though you use varying font sizes on a line? Below is an example where the second paragraph has a larger line spacing than the first one. I have tried to set line-height to 0 for the "huge" span in CSS, but it doesn't seem to be enough.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Line Spacing Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
}
.huge {
    font-size: 64px;
    line-height: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Here is a line using normal font size.<br />
Here is another line using normal font size.</p>

<p>Here is a line with a span with <span class="huge">huge</span> font
size.<br />
Here is another line with a span with <span class="huge">huge</span>
font size.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about `line-height`?

Comment: Remove `line-height` from `.huge` div

Comment: Won't help. Try it yourself and see.

Comment: So you'd like to have line spacing in whole p tag like it is with a `.huge` span in that line? Don't think it's possible.

Comment: well, the other way round. I want the lines with the .huge span to have the same line spacing as the ones without.

Comment: I ought to add that this example is not intended to be visually pleasing, I just want to know whether it's possible at all to keep the line spacing constant, regardless of varying font sizes, and regardless of overlapping glyphs.

Answer (score 2):

You can make line spacing constant only by setting it large enough to accommodate even the largest font used. By the specs, setting [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) on a block element sets the *minimum* height of line boxes. For inline elements, things are more complicated, but it boils down to letting browsers ultimately decide the heights of line boxes and hence the spacing.

On some browsers, however, you can persuade the browser to use your height e.g. by adding

```
span { display: inline-block; height: 16px; }
```

Comment: Yes, obviously it is rather complicated. Not as easy as forcing a fixed line spacing in OpenOffice Writer, for example. Thanks for your input, Jukka. I have read some really valuable stuff by you about HTML, CSS, Unicode, etc. on the net, for the record.